# XML signature default digest transformation

Tags: xml, xml-signature

I have a signature where where there is no transformations specified for the digested elements what should I use?

From the signature W3.org specification I found only that the default input for the next transformation, that requires character sequence, must be a canonical form C14 of the element set. But this seems not to work in my case.

Comment: It depends on the referenced content. The URI in the Reference would help to answer.

Comment: URI points to a node in the message.